# Internet Explorer dont show a piece of my site

Tags: php, html, css, cross-browser

i am creating a new site, based in a pre-existing web page

The original site is http://oasisrio.intermediasp.com/
Its works great in Firefox, Chrome, and IE

But the new one "oasisba.intermediasp.com"
Dont show the right bar in IE, i check all that i can think about and i dont found the problem.

Someone have any ideas why this is happening?

PD: Sorry for my crapy english

Comment: The right bar shows up for me on the "new" site  in IE6.

Comment: What part doesn't work? It looks the same in IE & Chrome for me. The left bar seems to be full of broken images in both.

Comment: the broken images are not a problem, is the demo, in internet explorer 8 the right bar is missing

Comment: I can confirm the right bar is missing when viewing the page using IE8. In IE8 "compatibility mode" it does appear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on how IE renders things, but you have some XHTML errors in your page.  I copied pasted the final source into an editor and it found a few things:

- `<meta>` tags aren't closed (should be `<meta />`)
- None of the `<img>` tags are closed (should be `<img />`)
- Several `<a>` anchors are `<A>` instead of the required lowercase, but their closing tag is `</a>` (lowercase)
- None of the `<br>` tags are closed (should be `<br />`)

But the thing that really jumped out to me was line #293 (just beneath the `<!-- FOOTER -->` marker) -- there is a `</div>`.  This tag is unmatched (no `<div>` tag).  I looked at the `index-content` section and it looks like there may be one extra `</div>` in there than there needs to be.

If you remove the `</div>` right above `<div id="map"></div>` -- does that change anything?  That's my best guess!

Comment: can you tell me the name of the editor to test that? ty

the last </div> dont change nothing :/ i test it

Comment: I used NetBeans 6.8.  I just viewed the source in IE and copied/pasted it into the editor.  Did anything change in the CSS between the working and non working versions?

Comment: nothing that i can find, i search both css files lines by line

Comment: Any changes in Javascript that is populating/manipulating the DOM?